# UFT - Random Date

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I create this code do get a random Date in a Range. I support it from some sites and answers here at stack from others. This works whit no problems, but when i try too pass at one function keep giving error.

```
StartDate = "01-01-1950"
EndDate= "31-12-2000"

StartDate = CDate(StartDate)
EndDate= CDate(EndDate)

Randomize
dtmRandomDate = DateValue((EndDate- StartDate + 1) * Rnd + StartDate )


Browser("DashBoard_2").Page("DashBoard").WebEdit("txtBornDate").Set dtmRandomDate
```

The error:

[image]

The function:

```
Function DataRandom(StartDate, EndDate)

    Dim StartDate, EndDate

    StartDate = CDate(StartDate)
    EndDate= CDate(EndDate)

    Randomize
    dtmRandomDate = EndDate((dtmEndDate - StartDate+ 1) * Rnd + StartDate)

End Function
```

I think the problem it's in the way i pass the Variables. Something about date functions that im missing it to declare, making the variable accept the date? It's something about the UFT system himself?

Already try somethings, but didnt worked.

Thank You,
Best Regards

Comment: You need to return the result from the Function, i.e `DataRandom = dtmRandomDate`. At the moment your `DataRandom()` function has no way to return a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can see from the test that it's failing on line 130;

```
a = DataRandom(01-02-2020, 03-04-2022)
```

There are two issues here:

1. The function `DateRandom()` expects to return a value but the function definition does not contain a statement to return the result and is behaving more like a Sub Procedure than a Function. To fix this change the Function definition to;

   ```
   Function DataRandom(StartDate, EndDate)
       Dim StartDate, EndDate

       StartDate = CDate(StartDate)
       EndDate = CDate(EndDate)

       Randomize 'Should be initialised once rather than with each call to the function.
       dtmRandomDate = DateValue((EndDate - StartDate + 1) * Rnd + EndDate)

       DateRandom = dtmRandomDate 'This line returns the result.
   End Function
   ```
2. The arguments being passed to the function are syntactically problematic, as you use `CDate()` to convert the values to correct `Date` you should pass the values as strings. Which just requires encapsulating each argument in double-quotes in the test.

   ```
   a = DataRandom("01-02-2020", "03-04-2022")
   ```

---

Also as pointed [out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62390902/uft-random-date/62393068?noredirect=1#comment110407279_62393068) the `Randomize` statement should only be run once rather than with each call to the function. Ideally you would have an `Init()` procedure that deals with the script setup and initialisation.

Comment: Hi @Lankymart, first let me thank you for your answer. Help alot. This happens when you are a Padawan on coding, yea i forgot to return the result. About the double-qoutes that i didnt forgor, just pass wrong at here. I will leave the full function to be integrate at Libray if someone needs at future. Thanks again. Regards.

Comment: No problem @Rik, glad it helped.

Comment: Please remove the call to Randomize out of the function. (Randomize should be called just once per session/run, because it initializes the generator)

Answer (score 1):

So getting the Lankymart help, the final function to put at libray.
Change the variables, or declare according your needs.

```
Public StartDate, EndDate

Function DateRandom(StartDate, EndDate)


    Dim dtmRandomDate, dtmStartDate, dtmEndDate

    dtmStartDate = CDate(StartDate)
    dtmEndDate = CDate(EndDate)

    dtmRandomDate = DateValue((dtmEndDate - dtmStartDate + 1) * Rnd + dtmStartDate)

    DateRandom = dtmRandomDate 'Returning the result

End Function
```

Comment: Please remove the call to Randomize out of the function. (Randomize should be called just once per session/run, because it initializes the generator)

Comment: Done @Ekkehard.Horner. But this means that if i don't call the Randomize anywhere else on the session/run i will have to call it whit the function anyway right?

Comment: For simple scripts, call Randomize at the start; for more complex cases, use a flag to make sure that it is called just once.